# Call nested Nuxt 3 route with absolute URL

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

Just a quick question, that I couldn't find an answer to.

I have two routes `"/"` and `"/auth"`.

```
-- pages
    -- auth
        -- index.vue
    -- index.vue
```

When I call `"/"` everything is fine. When I call `"/auth"` with a `<NuxtLink to="/auth" />` component, everything works.
But when I call the url `http://localhost:3000/auth` directly, I get the base Nuxt 3 404 error screen.

Is this a config setting I'm missing?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

If I want to use `yarn dev` I need to first call `yarn generate`.

Hope this helps someone else, too.

Comment: You should not normally.